# Get rid of the question ban on Meta; suspend actively harmful users manually

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, status-declined, meta, post-ban

[This user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/183189/mario-de-schaepmeester) appears to have been question banned because of two unpopular Meta suggestions. (He says so in [Chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1367437#1367437))

Look at the two contributions that appear to have gotten him banned. Like those of many others, they may not be of perfect quality, but they are not actively harmful to the site, either. As it stands, you can get question blocked on Meta simply for asking questions that aren't popular with the Meta crowd.

Why does the team insist on keeping the question ban active on Meta?

Why can't real problem users be dealt with through manual moderator action? Don't tell me it's a problem of scale; as far as I can see, actually toxic users are very rare on Meta.

People will frequently complain that Meta actively discourages the expression of unpopular viewpoints and suggestions. With the threat of question bans in place, I find those complaints difficult to refute. I hate that.

Comment: Actually, not just 2 questions, but probably it is because of his 2 recent suggestions that it hits the threshold. 5 of 16 of his questions are heavily downvoted (one -7, the other below -10). http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/183189/mario-de-schaepmeester?tab=questions&sort=votes

Comment: @nhahtdh But then I thought downvotes on discussions/feature requests express pure disagreement. If so: the "reason" I'm banned is completely unjust. If not: people should stop downvoting discussions.

Comment: Another user that (used to? said he was in comments on Apr. 29th) be Q-banned here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172312/158667

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester: I only provide the full picture here, since this post only mention the 2 recent questions that you got downvoted. I think question ban should still be there, but it should be reserved for trouble-maker proposing bad ideas all the times, which is not the case here.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109263/question-banning-should-work-differently-on-meta?rq=1

Comment: @nhahtdh: That's marked [meta-tag:status-completed]; hardly a duplicate IMO

Comment: @Bart: I know _one_ of his questions got downvoted into oblivion, but it wasn't a rant or particularly "disruptive". Just a really strange proposal. Not sure if there's other stuff in that user's past, but if there's only that that doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Mat As far as I recall there were at least 3 significantly downvoted contributions (-20 or lower). The former downvoted questions lead to his strange proposal which was heavily downvoted.

Comment: In an ideal world, a planet far removed from meta, there would be an option to appreciate a suggestion but have a way to cast a "let's not do that" vote.  This separate voting mechanism does in fact exist, it just isn't visible enough.  It would also avoid the repetitive "voting is different here" comments, the astonishment suffered by first-time meta visitors and some likelihood for more accurate representation of dis/agreement.

Comment: for the record, it was [already discussed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67023/152859).

Comment: For the record, the user is *not* banned because of those two questions...

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester: No, disagreement *can be a factor*. Downvotes do **not** equal disagreement. (Sorry, I just hate when people throw out the "it means disagreement" thing.) Relevant information: [[1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153145)] [[2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146057)] and maybe [[3](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/rant/info)]

Comment: I would like to add that I've also **never** received a warning about the imminence of my question ban. Just boom, there it was and it left me completely stumped. If you're going to do something as relatively serious and radical as this, at least you could **warn** me that it could happen if I don't make better posts.

Comment: I [ran across a similar situation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116008/can-negatively-received-feature-requests-lead-to-a-question-ban) once.

Comment: Have a look at this comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179042/please-assume-good-faith-whenever-reasonable-when-dealing-with-post-banned-users/179058#comment542149_179057.  A completely unnecessary "*miséricorde*", and this really should not have happened.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery Let's just say there might be alternative views to that particular situation, which don't entirely match the author's description. Though I still support this feature request.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery - You keep using the word "miséricorde", and from what I can gather from googling, it is a French word for mercy. However, context indicates that you think that miséricordes are bad. Aren't you trying to advocate for mercy upon question-banned users?

Comment: @JackManey: The issue at hand is that I want to see fewer users complaining about post bans that are unjustified.  My goal here is to minimize unnecessary post bans and resolve improper post bans as quickly as possible, so that good-faith users don't end up having to cry for mercy.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery Curious though. Where do you get your "this really should not have happened" from? Are you aware of the particular history of that case? Or do you simply mean that Meta bans should not happen?

Comment: @JackManey: Upon looking at the comments again, I realized that the user I mentioned didn't do a good job at making feature requests here, and the accusations of serial downvoting are probably unjustified.  However, given that the user has a record of contributing good answers on Meta, the post ban doesn't really make sense.  I think a warning and appropriate manual moderator action really would have been a better way to handle this case.

Comment: Another example of how the Stack Exchange format is completely wrong for Meta, which is _really_ a "forum". It's been shoe-horned in, going  against everything SE stands for. Look at the Meta FAQ, for example, most of which is completely inappropriate for Meta.

Comment: What about users who got banned on the main site and start asking their programming questions here on Meta? It's very convenient they get auto blocked after a while, without any need for moderator intervention.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I believe that currently can already lead to a specific suspension (i.e. Asked programming questions on Meta).

Comment: @Bart true, but it's very rarely used as far as I can see.

Comment: "Why does the team insist on keeping the question ban active on Meta?"  Because even though they like to say that votes on Meta are different, they really aren't.  They are exactly the same in every way that matters.

Comment: the *only* reason for bans should be a. spamming b. personal insults. Everything else, if done in good faith, is part of a discussion. ***On The Discussion Site!*** And yes, I'm banned too, and no, I did not post spam or personal insults. I have one deleted question which I assert I had every right to raise, too (and two unpopular suggestions after the last of which I got immediately banned). Until this policy is retracted and apologies are made to all the abused by it (myself included) I've imposed an answer ban on SO, myself.

Comment: [Bingo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126590/do-downvotes-on-meta-truly-mean-something-different/126604#126604), @John

Comment: How can this be `status-completed` («[...] has been implemented [...]») and `status-declined` («[...] will not be implemented [...]»)!?

Comment: +∞ I'm "in danger of being question banned" because I had ideas and tried to contribute to the site.

Comment: @JMCF125 See the first section of [Shog's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197335/278659).

Comment: [@Shog9's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197335/351462) should be set as the accepted answer, if only because it explains the use of both `status-completed` and `status-declined` on a single question

Comment: @Stevoisiak Well it's also the most correct response, too. Completely removing the automatic question ban would be *horrible* for Stack Overflow, at least.

Comment: How can it both be *"status-completed"* and *"status-declined"*?

Answer (score 70):

[EDIT - see modifications (@ post end) based on Bart bringing this to our attention again.]

Today, having watched my first question (a feature request) here on Meta drop to **-6** with no bottom in sight, I immediately got discouraged. Then a kind comment mentioned that downvotes meant mere disagreement about using or implementing the suggestions.

And then I found this thread.

Scary.

As a noob, having read many of these related posts, I'd say there is a large elephant in the room with 'double standard' painted on its side. (If you want to shoot a newly arrived messenger and ban *me* for "whining" or "complaining," or down vote me to heck, so be it.)

You got problems here. Problems that need human, not robotic, intervention, with human compassion, not bull-headed, superficial statistical analysis driving a robot. (Gads MDeSchaepmeester had TWO -12 voted questions and he was tossed?  I read them - they were not dangerous or mean-spirited, not even annoying. In fact, what happened to him makes me want to Self-Ban.)

How can people be banned for "bad" (*) ideas on a site that is *intended for meta-level discussions*?  Moreover, unless the FAQ is hypocritical and Meta is not really "run by the community," how can robotic blacklisting be tolerated?  Worse, the posts I've read indicate the one banned has no recourse or appeal - other than making comments as here.

(*) "Bad" is a fuzzy logic concept, "Up or Down" votes are only binary. Therefore the existing voting methodology cannot possibly encompass meta-level questions, which by their nature must be more sophisticated than fuzzy logic.

Commentators <del>should be</del> can be constructively critical *[if they want]* and say WHY an idea is bad --- which is what happened in my case (the idea would be too heavy data-wise, it could be done better in other ways, etc.) [***EDIT***: searches show the sub-topic of requiring comment on down vote has been discussed to near beat-the-horse-dead status]

[**EDIT 23AUG13** - side discussions lead me to withdraw the sub-suggestions of a down vote requiring a comment. Ditto a sliding vote scale (which I *might* suggest in the future): ]

<del>I'd say, ***only here on META***, unless you are a moderator, or posting-god/-goddess you should not be allowed to down vote without a small comment as to why. OR the up / down voting should be changed to a sliding scale of 1 to 10 ... seriously, how can a Meta discussion be pidgin-holed into yes-no tallies?</del>

As others here have voiced, banning should only be done by real people - and more than one ... perhaps at least three, high-level moderators - and only with due cause. And there needs to be an appeal mechanism. Otherwise "by the community" is mere double speak.

[ Edit after a day of comments below] Why no technical solution ? If there is some robo-banner banning people automagically, it does so using a threshold.

Simply replace:

`if (threshold > bad) { ban_em ; }`

with

`if (threshold > bad) { notify_review_board ; }`
// clearly the mechanism is there already with flagging.

@random & Bart: by *high-level* or *posting-god/-goddess*, I mean at least a *trusted user*.    Perhaps a good review board could be composed of a true cross sampling of the user community. An SE employee (in rotation, if need), at least two trusted users, two moderators, and two or three users below 500 - even include a near-noob like me (level allowed to up-vote and down-vote).  When they get notified, they decide by equal-weighted majority, one person, one vote.  This seems to me to be the only fair way to ban someone.

And if that seems like too much work for everyone, merely set the *bad threshold* higher. Notifying the board less would not thereby cause more bad posts from getting through, because the community can still bring nasty stuff to the proper attention via the flag mechanism.

I agree with notPekka - more human intervention. Consider it this way: when a human being's free actions are to be hindered, judgment should be passed by his fellow humans.  If the speed trap's radar catches my car, photographs my license plate, then generates a ticket mailed to me, I still have the right to contest it in front of real people.  We will rue the day when the speed trap sends us fine notices that are incontestable.

---

**[ EDIT 16 SEPT 13 ]** - With Bart resurfacing this issue and comments since I posted this answer, my suggestion warrants an addition.

**This improvement is also simple**, extending the earlier version.

Merely add in another *threshold* variable to prevent valuable contributors on StackOverflow (or any Stack Exchange site) from being "**auto-banned**" while still bringing "questionable" posts to the appropriate attention *without the need of users' flagging*.

As an example, the version below - compared to the previous version - is rendered in a *stricter* fashion on the low side and more permissive on the high. In other words, (auto)-watch newer users closer, but **normal ethical users get a free pass from auto-banning. HOWEVER, if** any post has **"excessive" downvoting,** then bring it to Moderator attention, just *don't* auto-ban willy nilly. Clearly such simple rules could be tailored easily to find the right levels.

```
//  Quality of activity thresholds 
//
//    First If block = a simple "high-pass" filter
//    Second If bloc = high value trigger  
//

SE_REP_THRESHOLD = 500  // community or SE owners pick appropriate Rep value.

//
// Modified version of previous suggestion
// 

// Get user's highest rep across all the Stack sites the user participates in. 
// This info is already in our profiles.

usersHighRepScore = get_UsersHighestRepScore (allStackExchageSites) 

if (downvote_threshold > bad) AND ( usersHighRepScore < SE_REP_THRESHOLD ) { 
    // next could be optional 
    ban_em ;             // LOW BLOCK - auto-ban prevents spam too 
    notify_moderators ;  // notify also optional, if we want to be " nicer " & unban later
}

// *Optional* High trap filter - high down vote AND high rep 
//  = post is "provocative enough" - someone should see what's up.

if (downvote_threshold > bad ) AND ( usersBestRepScore > SE_REP_THRESHOLD ) {   
   notify_review_board ; 
}
```

Comment: When you say high level moderator, you mean paid, employed staff of SE?

Comment: What is a "posting-god/-goddess" and by what criteria would they be excluded from having to leave comments? (P.s. the whole comments for downvotes idea is a tricky one. Even on Meta).

Comment: Seriously, why are people downvoting this?

Comment: I'd say because they disagree with some of the proposed ideas/changes/functionalities @ColeJohnson.

Comment: I agree, just one note: profiles with question bans usually have deleted questions on them. The visible track record isn't usually all of why a user got banned, which is why it's misleading to look only at that.

Comment: @Howard you can add more comments here - the chat room thing is just a recommendation.

Comment: @Bart - Good call --- I've since come to understand reasons why comments for downvotes is tricky; have struck that from my answer.

Comment: I agree with your "speeding ticket" analogy - as long as it's about Meta. On the main site, with its 7,000+ new questions a day, the question ban is essential to keeping us all sane. It's more like a ticket barrier there - if you haven't bought a ticket, the system won't let you in. If you think that's happened in error, you need to walk to the booth and speak to the attendant.

Comment: @notPekka - yes to only on Meta ... think it was Bart who pointed out the traffic is low enough here. To continue your analogy: is Meta missing the booth attendant ?

Comment: For the record, MDeSchaepmeester is not currently banned from asking questions on Meta. I believe the three downvoted and deleted questions may have worked against them, in addition to the several other downvoted questions they had. Aside from that, [I have had my problems with the question ban on Meta, too.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67023/should-the-automated-ban-on-questions-used-on-so-apply-to-meta-as-well)

Comment: @BradLarson - are there any links to how / why MDeSchaepmeester (and you?) were reinstated? Clearly, we users need to understand this better. (I personally got very worried that my initial steps into Meta would meet with disaster because several of my posts were going down fast ... spent a fair and reasonable time trying to understand *before* my answer here - I was truly concerned I'd be locked out.)

Comment: @BradLarson Do you happen to know the specific algorithm for question banning? Absent that information, I feel I need to stop asking any MSO question that mentions the possibility of any change or expresses any opinion that might be at odds with the predominant culture.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin - No, moderators don't have any indication of the algorithm used, just if someone is banned or not (and that was only added recently). I do know that it's been stated that the Meta question ban algorithm is very relaxed when compared to the SO one. I don't think you have much to worry about, because it really seems to take a lot for this to be tripped on Meta and you're nowhere near that with as many upvoted questions as you have.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks. So even if my -40 question continues its record-setting pace, I still should be ok?  In other words, you're pretty sure it's more a matter of % of questions with negatives as opposed to    aggregate negative?

Comment: check out my record. I was autobanned immediately after my last question. Scary for you, maddeningly unjust, for me. Chin up! @BradLarson relaxed it is not. You can probably see my deleted question (I can't, and don't even know the score there). I assert I was in my right to ask that question, and I protest it being removed from the record; and without any doubt I had every right to make the two proposals that finally got me banned. Autobanning is incredibly intrusive, oppressive, demeaning, dehumanizing, take your pick. Stifling the debate on a debate site has no merit. **None.**

Comment: re "Self-Ban". **I did exactly that.** Not here (obviously!) but on SO itself. I demand this policy withdrawn and apologies issued to all who were wronged by this before I consider lifting ***my*** self-ban.

Comment: and it's a **sad judgment on this community** that this answer has only 19 up-score (how many downvotes you've received, I have no way of knowing).

Comment: @WillNess if I read the record in my profile correctly, there have been only 2 downvotes total so far. Insignificant numerically, really. Yet there is a weird thing about those two votes: they were the very first two votes rcv'd and happened within 3 hrs of the answer's posting - the first within 20 minutes. It didn't really turn until Cole Johnson's first comment above. Sorry you got banned - it seems very bizarre and truly sad since you have a near 14k rep on S.O main. You of all people should have a right to voice even a strong negative opinion here.  Another answer possible ...

Comment: @HowardPautz yes, there are only 2 downvotes (as of this comment).

Comment: @psubsee2003 thx for verification ... was pretty sure, but never hurts to get a qualified 2nd opinion - especially re a topic as challenging as this one is :))

Comment: Why do you think folks should get a pass for their behavior here based on their behavior elsewhere?

Comment: @Shog9 correct me if I'm wrong, but recall I asked on chat where the meta.meta site is, and you promptly replied meta.se. therefore anyone w/ "high" rep on any stack site should be considered a respected user worthy of posting on meta.se without concern of auto banning. That pseudo code only passes them through the auto-banner gate, but if they goof up "bad" enough, then you all as mods would be notified. Actually think this could be very effective, IFF the parms were set correctly. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Not sure how that follows - everyone *is* enabled to post here; that doesn't mean they can *keep* posting here. You're just suggesting we replace an automatic ban with a manual one. Just trying to understand the rationale here.

Comment: A pass for what behavior, @Shog9? What behavior? Is this a prep school? Is this a boarding school? Is this a military academy? What behavior?

Comment: @HowardPautz **anyone** has a right "to voice even a strong negative opinion here". ***Anyone***. The only things that got to ban someone *here* is spamming or personal attacks. IM personal strongly held O.

Comment: @WillNess I disagree. No one has a right to do anything, it is neither school nor a military academy. SE can set its own rules. Part of the reason for those rules is to help keep the site clean.  I support some manner of changing the ban on Meta, but it has to go beyond personal attacks and spamming.  But there are people that don't do their research or continually post nonsense feature requests, or continually post completely wrong answers.  Why should they be allowed to continue and possibly annoy your loyal users. So a ban must be implemented, but I'd support modifying it in some manner.

Comment: @WillNess but depending on how many deleted posts you have (anhd their score), your record would seem to be the type of person we're trying to help here.  So some sort of manual review process might be interesting

Comment: @psubsee2003 you disagree with something I never said. :) Anyone has right to participate in discussions on a discussion site, in a constructive manner, is what I'm saying. Of course what's constructive or not, is subjective. Certainly not a matter for automatons to decide (at the present AI state of the art). "why should they be allowed to annoy loyal users" because they are people too. If that's their way to provoke debate, they have every right for it. We could allow for negative reputation to make such situations clear. And then they will deliver something extremely positive/popular...!!!

Comment: @psubsee2003 moreover, a positive contribution might be very unpopular, and only be seen as such in retrospect. And the score might not even get corrected with time, but looking back you'd see that the contribution *was* indeed for the better. This might or might not be the case with my deleted (extremely downvoted) question, for one example. It depends on when and why was the feature added to SE, enabling users to *easily* upload their own identicons on SE instead of those supplied by Gravatar.

Comment: I think the "get a pass" comment is really telling here. The prevailing premise in the MSO culture/system is that opinions that a lot people disagree with are "bad". Rather than allowing ideas that are crazy, impractical, or have some horrible side effect to be viewed as potentially _constructive_ contributions to the process of brainstorming and problem solving, such ideas invoke the machinery (downvoting) of devaluing, silencing and banning. As in any oppressive society, conversation gets driven underground - in MSO's case to the world of comments.

Comment: @Shog9 (and all) my suggestion is intended to do two things: eliminate incorrect / unjustified auto-banning and bring to attention posts that may (or may not!) be problematic. On the hotter political aspects being voiced here, the definition of what constitutes "problematic" is a matter for the community to decide. Personally, and as I said in my answer, I think we should err on the side of openness. But in sites like SO, we can set more gatekeepers to reduce the moderator workload. Gates again meaning "control of out-of-norm" posts ("norm" too is to be decided and would probably be site ...

Comment: ... specific. )  The approach could be both less and more automated, allowing the mods / community / owners to set the gate parms. Every person clearly already has a "pass" but if a post goes out of norm then ...

Comment: Just to be clear: no one gets banned for posting an unpopular post. A *history* of badly-received posts may get you banned (although the threshold on MSO is pretty high/low/lax - your stuff can't just be a *little bit* unpopular). In some cases, the folks hitting the ban have been outright abusive, but in almost all cases they've at very least been wasting the time of the folks who review feature-requests, analyze bug reports, and attempt to provide feedback. At some point, you gotta draw a line and say, "there are other folks who need to use this site, stop hogging the commons with your crap"

Comment: @Shog9 Please also clarify how that line is drawn. "[...] say, '...stop hogging' ... ".  Who's doing the initial "saying" there, who or what is triggering that the line has been crossed ? Is it an algorithm first, then moderators / owners ? NotPekka's OP suggests it's an algo. All I'm saying is make that algo more sophisticated, more nuanced. It will also reduce your workload because it will cut the crap sooner, if set correctly --- you see where I'm trying to go with this ?

Comment: It's an algorithm, @Howard - driven by the community's collective responses to previous activity. Who would you prefer took on that role?

Comment: @Shog9 Sorry, but I'm a bit befuddled - I am wondering now if my answers and comments are so unclear that you were prompted to ask me this.  Shouldn't banning be the task of real people, aided by the algorithm, not the other way round ? (And that question, IMO, sums up this entire question set.)

Comment: The only purpose of the ban is to *remove* the need for individuals to micromanage these things - there&#39;s a pretty big group of us who can already handle them manually if/when we have the time and inclination to do so. Take away the automation, and we might as well just disable it entirely. That said - it's not like there aren't Real People involved, from the folks voting up to those of us who can review individual blocks; the system exists to assist.

Comment: @Shog9 precisely !  I'm *not* suggesting we take away the automation, rather that we make it more surgically precise. Right now, it seems pretty clear from the comments here and also that this question is currently running in several threads, that more than a few users find the automation instrument to be a bludgeon, not a scalpel. We need lasers, not nukes.

Comment: Developing an entirely new form of suspension for the sole benefit of meta probably isn't going to happen, @Howard. That said, see my answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually/197335#197335

Comment: @Shog9 yes, excellent - I read and up voted your answer (regardless of my own answer :) --- yours and the efforts of others involved addresses my answer's salient concerns while using real data was good the get the 'q-ban' thresholds reset (thanks for doing that). (Although it's moot now, I didn't really want a "new form of suspension", rather the suggestions made were toward tweaking what we have - so it looks like that was considered.) And, BTW, what has transpired here has given me a much higher confidence in the fairness and objectivity of the community.

Comment: What has happened to this answer! I remember happily upvoting it but its become a mess of edits and replys to comments :(

Comment: @RichardTingle - to point you in the right direction through the "mess of edits": two answers have bonuses attached, mine here and Shog9's final answer. His efforts and those of many others at least indirectly incorporate many of the concerns I voiced. I am satisfied by the outcome. The whole deal put my respect for the mods and community folks up *several* notches.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose, I just remember really liking this answer before and I feel like I could really like it again. It has a real feel of "Time" at the moment though, like it was written as several different points (which of course it was)

Comment: Still fully valid as of 20190320045502.

Answer (score 57):

First off, an explanation of the two status tags:

- **Declined**: We won't remove the q-ban entirely. See below.
- **Completed**: We already suspend *actively harmful* users manually, and will continue to do so. In addition, we've modified the score threshold for q-bans ([again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109263/question-banning-should-work-differently-on-meta/123068#123068)) based on a fresh analysis of the data - at this point, it is low enough that it should be *extremely* difficult to hit "accidentally" - if you're able to contribute to the community here in any consistently constructive fashion (for instance, providing helpful answers to [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions), you can get away with posting the odd unpopular [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). In a sense, you can earn the right to be occasionally annoying by being generally helpful. In *no* cases will expressing an unpopular viewpoint block you from further participation, unless you do it repeatedly *and* that's **the only thing you do.**

### Community service vs. imprisonment

This site serves as the "nation's capital", and as such there are many people here from many different backgrounds and with many different concerns - concerns that deserve to be heard and addressed. It *is* important that dissenting viewpoints can be expressed, but it is also not fair to give anyone with a bone to pick an unlimited soapbox on which to stand and shout.

As I said, we do and will continue to issue suspensions for users who are abusive or disruptive to the communities here. If you're being overtly offensive to others - or even just an overly-disruptive nuisance - you'll get at least a short time-out.

However, suspension is a much more blunt instrument for dealing with folks who, for whatever reason, simply cannot seem to ever post a useful *question*. Unlike suspensions, you can "work your way out" of a q-ban: just post some helpful or insightful answers. The vast majority of people who use this site are in no danger of ever being blocked from posting a question *because* they've taken the time to participate constructively in the past, but even for those who start off on the wrong foot and... follow up by jumping up and down on that foot... it's not too late to reverse the trend: take the time to learn about how this network of sites work, share your knowledge with others, and you'll be automatically granted permission to post questions again. No need to wait out a suspension or try to bargain with a moderator - earn the privilege and it's yours to use.

Philosophically, I like this sort of **merit-based restriction** a *lot* better than suspension. Even if *in practice* both mean than someone can't post questions for a few months, the former puts this decision squarely in the hands of the participant themselves and the community they wish to be a part of.

Big thanks to everyone here for their input, and to Anna Lear, Tim Post, Jon Ericson and Grace Note for taking the time to sanity-check the data and talk over the philosophy behind this internally.

Comment: upvoted not because I agree with your reasoning (I agree but this doesn't matter here) but for making a _fantastic_ case of a feature request having both [meta-tag:status-completed] and [meta-tag:status-declined]

Comment: In theory, users can work themselves out of a question ban.  In practice, for whatever reason, I suspect that they seldom do.  The ones that do get themselves out of a ban sometimes use techniques that... let's just say are not representative of reform.  Automatic bans, while appearing to be fair in the sense that they can be worked out of, are not only of indeterminate duration but (because we don't state the rules due to gaming reasons) appear somewhat arbitrary in execution.

Comment: All that said, since quality filters were put into place, I seldom find a need to suspend anyone, and since the process is free of human decision, it should be a fairly impartial process, since the rules are presumably applied equally to everyone.

Comment: I'd love to see some of the practical outcomes of this regarding previously banned user (some of whom I really think shouldn't have been), but I guess we'll see that if then end up participating again. But overall I can live with this if it's indeed as "reasonable" in practice.

Comment: @Robert: the vast, *vast* majority of banned users don't even try. Of those who do make any effort, a depressingly large number don't want help asking better questions, they want the ban lifted so they can ask more crappy ones. URGENTLY. Of the few that remain, the recovery rate ain't bad. I agree we could stand to improve the guidance for this though.

Comment: "In no cases will expressing an unpopular viewpoint block you from further participation, unless you do it repeatedly and that's the only thing you do." - In other words: someone with an off-mainstream opinion better say something that the majority wants to hear from time to time. Isn't this a ridiculous view even if in practice it might work to some extent? I always say that you can very well see how liberal a community is by analyzing how it treats those who think differently.

Comment: Some of us take the occasional time-out from expressing our opinions to help others learn to use the site effectively, @Trilarion. Helping your comrades is an *excellent* way to avoid ostracization. Incidentally, when someone on meta tells me I should be doing more to help new users I always check their profile - if they haven't touched the [meta-tag:support] tag, I laugh at their hypocrisy and move on.

Comment: Don't misunderstand me - Helping others is an excellent idea and I support it a lot. Only connecting it to allowing expressing unpopular viewpoints just seems like connecting two things that have no real connection. Just in case someone had a very unpopular view he better hope there is also somebody who needs help. If not it might be just bad luck. I don't think there is any good reason to punish unpopular opinions other than suppressing them.

Comment: It's not just an excellent idea, @Trilarion - it's one of the underpinnings of a healthy site. If someone is not here to seek or provide help, then they really don't need to be here at all. Again, no one gets blocked for one or two mistakes... But if their participation here over time is *relentlessly* unhelpful, then they're just getting in the way of the folks who actually want to use the site for one of its intended purposes; neither the rest of us nor the system itself are under any obligation to continue providing them with a soapbox.

Comment: Being unhelpful can mean that 40% of readers liked your idea and the rest not. I think you mix two things that aren't related and come up with a recipe (unpopular opinions are allowed but only to some extent) that cannot be clearly motivated and is easily attackable. Since noone else did it, I stepped in and provided the main counter arguments. You only achieve less unpopular opinions with it. In my eyes this is not helpful since the score already gives a measure of unhelpfulness, no need to ban anyone. I downvoted because I think it effectively just punishes minority opinions.

Comment: It can also mean you're bad at searching or persistently ask programming questions here, even after multiple suspensions, @Trilarion... But ignoring practical matters, this idea that we should be providing a *perpetual soapbox* for anyone with an axe to grind is, IMHO, just silly. I repeat: anyone can post here, and most of the time we'll hear them out even if we disagree; everyone gets multiple chances to make a compelling persuasive argument; no one has infinite goodwill. If you honestly believe I'm wrong about that last point, propose this in your own discussion - I'll tell you a story...

Answer (score 31):

As the person whose question prompted Pekka to put a bounty on this, I can say that it IS frustrating when you spot improvements or errors and are not allowed to contribute this information.

By nature, I'm a helper.  I spend HOURS a day on this site in the MS-Access, VBA and SQL portions of SO answering questions.  I received the Tenacious badge because I continue to answer questions even when some people would have gotten frustrated.  No "thank you", no points, no checkmarks...  and still I answer questions because I know what it's like to be a n00b.

Once in a while, I get frustrated too, and I construct a poorly worded question on Meta.  It wasn't harmful, it wasn't offensive, it was just maybe too much of a "b*tch session" and got hammered.  So now I can't ask questions?  The system is broken if that's the current way to handle it.  And I don't know how to, or if there's even a WAY to, get un-banned?

Comment: You will get unbanned by gaining rep other ways (this answer for example, and other meta answers) along with suggested edits. If you have questions that were downvoted not for disagreement but for poor quality, you could try improving them in the hope of the downvotes being removed.

Comment: I think the questions were kind of dogs to begin with.  They were early in my Meta career.  In retrospect, they shouldn't have been asked at all.  But there's no way to go back and undo them.

Comment: @KateGregory is the algorithm for this process posted anywhere ? Are you saying that simply gaining rep will cross the bad-now-good threshold and the question-banned user automagically can post questions again? Are they notified via email - or do they just have to poll-hack every once in a while to discover they're not robo-fodder anymore ?

Comment: no it is deliberately not posted. Some folks have drawn some conclusions from observations, mostly on SO. You might be interested in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172300/what-happens-to-folks-who-get-question-banned-by-and-large

Comment: Since posting this, you've "[worked your way out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually/197335#197335)" of the ban - thanks to well-reasoned answers such as this one. If we had suspended you, that wouldn't have been possible - answers such as this would've gone unposted. I'm happy to have a system that lets folks such as yourself participate in constructive ways - enjoy the privileges you've earned!

Comment: @Shog9 - Yes, I HAVE worked my way out of it.  But, if anything, that shows the flaw in autobahns.  The questions I got downvoted on could easily have been questions that people didn't agree with.  19 downvotes and you're screwed.  But 19 out of however many total participants here is a MINISCULE percentage.  I still contend there needs to be some manual intervention because downvotes on Meta are supposed to be agree/disagree, and not good question/bad question.

Comment: It took a **lot** more than 19 downvotes, @Johnny. I see -19 followed by -17 followed by -3, -3, +7, -3, +1, +1, -20 - not a good average over a pretty decent-sized sample. At that point, it took about a month to recover, during which time you posted most of your answers. With yesterday's changes, it'd take you longer to hit the block (even if your initial pattern continued) and less time to get out of it - but even as things stood a month ago, I can't really say the results were *bad*.

Answer (score 18):

While I agree with and have upvoted this proposal (this site is different and low-traffic enough for it to work), perhaps it's a reasonable idea to consider an alternative as well, in case this turns out to be a no go. Primarily because Meta is also a place for support questions, having a couple of bad feature requests or not constructive posts should not exclude you from help or reporting bugs.

In that light, perhaps only ban users from question which do not have the [support](/questions/tagged/support) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tags. This would still allow them to report issues and get support, perhaps giving them an additional option to redeem themselves.

Of course, if users were to abuse this privilege, they could be put on a suspension from the site. Maybe even through an automatic moderator flag were one of their posts to be retagged to something other than the aforementioned tags.

Comment: A user may make 20 suggestions with -40 score, and still be able to make his next suggestion something completely brilliant that changes the entire SE network to its very core, granting him eternal fame. Unlikely of course, and I've definitely no ambition to do so myself, but you get the idea.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester As you say, unlikely. Several poor suggestions, especially when made within a short span of time, seems to be more indicative of the user not taking the time to look through the history of and reasoning behind features that make up the site. But you will most likely have read that I agree with the proposed feature at the beginning of my answer. Though I think it's unlikely to be implemented. But maybe I'm a pessimist.

Comment: I do know the reasoning here more or less, and I admit that I would not have posted some of my questions when viewing them a couple of days later. And indeed, I already suspect that some of my suggestions will be downvoted before I post them even, but I'm usually too optimistic about them. But then again I wonder: does that even **bother** people? It's not as if there's a steady stream of new questions on meta every minute, that people are already too busy handling all bad suggestions. I am entitled to share my idea, even if people aren't like-minded. That's what downvotes are for.

Comment: Sure, no argument there. And if we have users ranting over and over again, adding nothing constructive to the site, they just can be suspended for a while to cool off. So I agree with the request here. My answer is more of an alternative if the response would be "not gonna happen".

Comment: The "I probably wouldn't have supported my own request after a couple days" remark is the nail here. You really just need to bring that sort of thing to a happening SE chat somewhere and open a dialog with others, rattle the cages so to speak, and see what is left at the end of the discussion. That is how I do most of my FRs, and as you can see, a lot of them are actually downvoted, or at least not heavily upvoted, so it's fair to suggest that maybe you just need more maturity on the network. But I do agree with the OP here on we should abolish that on meta.se

Comment: @jcolebrand -- I don't follow what you are saying. Just because someone changes their mind doesn't make the original suggestion bad for Meta. Even if the suggestion is *bad* that doesn't hurt Meta. For a counter-example, my own mostly highly-upvoted meta question is a proposal that I changed my mind on with a couple days, and now (a year later) I fully disagree with my former self. But that doesn't change anything about the usefulness of the question itself being on meta.

Comment: Point taken, and well made.

Comment: -1. you have no right to silence me on any tag on meta, except for spam postings or making personal insults . Anything else is a discussion, made in good faith, on a discussion site. If I see something that I consider a grave problem I may even come out as uneasily grating and "offensive" to some; that's my right in the discussion, as long as it's not personal, i.e. name calling, but rather about merits of the issue at hand.

Comment: You did of course read my answer and subsequent comments stating I fully agree with the idea proposed by the OP @WillNess? And that my solution is merely meant as an alternative in case it is decided to decline the request?

Comment: No, I didn't. I saw that you allow for bans for reasons other than spam or extreme rudeness. I see your proposal as allowing the abuse  to continue but at the same time try to find ways to use the abused (i.e. autobanned) more efficiently.

Comment: From my comments @WillNess *"My answer is more of an alternative if the response would be "not gonna happen"."*

Comment: yes, I understand. But then comes the other part, you know. To which my comments apply. What can I say. :)

Comment: I see you've started a bonus. Very much appreciated! I wanted to do it myself, but I was afraid I'd loose even commenting "privileges". Cheers. :)

Comment: I'm downvoting this since I don't think you should be subject to question bans on ***any*** tag. Posting feature requests or discussions where people happen to disagree with you doesn't mean you should be question banned.

Comment: What's this crazy talk about me being a good guy @HowardPautz? Just the thought of it! ... :) But yeah, I can see where you're coming from. Like I've said before, this is at most an alternative to at least be able to still get support. But only if the actual proposal does not get through.

Comment: IOW there's no compromising with Evil, no searching for middle ground with Evil; and question ban on meta is Evil. Cheers. :) (just to clarify my train of thought).

Comment: @WillNess you might want to be a bit more clear though. Are you suggesting such a ban is evil? :p

Comment: @Bart yes, I think that question ban on meta on grounds other than spamming, personal attacks and insults, just for raising uneasy problems or unpopular suggestions is Evil. -- even on SO itself, the automatic unannounced indefinite incontestable question ban is Evil too.

Comment: Just kidding @WillNess. Your 3 "Evil"s made that abundantly clear. ;)

Comment: @Bart but I just realized that about SO as well. :) when a new guy asks his first question on SO, there should be a warning about this auto-ban thing in Big Fat Red (non-Greek) letters.

Comment: @Bart  aha, so this was a joke. now it is funny to me too, reading back. having a laugh. :)

Comment: "if users were to abuse this..." Not "if", *when*. Tag-based exemptions just encourage tag-abuse - don't need more of that.

Comment: @Shog9 luckily we have no such problems with any of the other features on the sites. :p But point taken.

Comment: as one data point, I'm no longer q-banned.

Answer (score 12):

I think this phenomenon is a case of the MSO design telling us it has a problem. In particular, I think the use of downvoting for disagreement as well as quality is inconsistent with various aspects of SE, including the automatic question ban. If we work around this with manual intervention for the question ban matter, we'll just be putting off dealing with the underlying issue.

Comment: The voting system is somewhat awkward and inconsistent. But I really don't think we need something else, other than a revision of the Meta ban. The big "problem" is a feature-request in this case. And if the community's votes had any direct influence on the decision of whether or not a feature is implemented, then I'd argue that we'd need a good voting system for it. But while we can have our say, and put in our yays and nays, it's ultimately the higher-ups within SO/SE who decide. So I personally think a simple revision of how we ban users (or if whether we ban them at all) should suffice.

Comment: @Bart Thing is, it's not just bona fide "feature requests" that are getting downvoted. It's any question that includes any idea/opinion that the most active MSO users don't "like" (or are tired of hearing about). This has the effect of driving people away or at least keeping them from asking questions with ideas which might challenge the status quo, and I don't think that's good for MSO and ultimately SO. Also, and I could be wrong about this, my understanding is that there is no "top down rule" and the the key decisions are indeed made by the "community" (i.e. based on votes).

Comment: As far as feature request are concerned, I don't really have that impression. We can make a good case for it, but to say we make the decisions, nah. As for downvotes because we're "tired of hearing about" it, that pretty much falls under the "no research" clause. We're not tired of hearing about good questions. We're tired of seeing the exact same discussions pop up time and time again. The research requirement holds on Meta as well. If that drives users away, I'm not sure I can sympathize that much with them. I do however sympathize with those unlucky feature requesters who got banned.

Comment: my favorite is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191861/165773). With only [first trolling comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191861/how-to-tag-questions-related-to-size-of-close-votes-review-queue-at-stack-overfl#comment597624_191861 "'downvoting this for now since you need to clarify what the issue is'") remaining (further trolling comments from _both_ sides are removed / visible only to mods), it makes a great example of senseless voting: "How dare you ask a _question_ when you are supposed to whine about an _issue_"

Comment: @gnat That is classic. And it's interesting how often the same names show up lecturing if not ridiculing people that seem like they're honestly trying to understand and operate within the system/culture.

Comment: yet another example - try to guess _why_ [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194863/165773) has got two downvotes. I expect usual gang to pop up with their usual cliche _don't-whine-about-downvotes_, but that's hardly an explanation of _why_

Comment: @gnat I would guess they're taking issue with the premise that new content should never be added, but who knows. I do find it a little odd that when I attempt to add a new answer I get prompted with "are you sure don't want to try and make the existing one better"? if the expectation is that only inferable improvements should be made, that seems a little odd.

Comment: @gnat I've been struggling to find a physical analogy for downvoting something that isn't a bona fide yes/no proposal. I recently came up with "electric shock from an unknown source". It's not fatal, but its painful and it's completely counterproductive for shaping behavior in any kind of constructive way.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin regarding editing approach, you have an interesting note here. I would rather rephrase to "only inferable improvements are _safe_", meaning that practically, anything can slip through the system, it's not perfect; "inferable" stuff is just safer and guaranteed to feel right by the vast majority (myself included)...

Comment: @gnat :-) It's going to take me a while get the notion of "should" out of my system when it comes to MSO. This truly is a "lawless" place. You've got the SE/MSO software, free will, moderators doing what they think best and "documentation" which tries to characterize what group behavior will be in response to various actions. No stinkin' policies. ;-)

Comment: lawless places are fertile ground for _pack mentality_. When community norms are shaky, many feel unsafe; this makes them wish to join a pack. Pack members have to give up part of their identity and reason "in return" (this seems to be typically obscured by vomiting _anonymousvoting_ slogan over and over and over again) but for some, this probably is an acceptable compromize

Comment: Insightful answer and comments @PeterAlfvin

Answer (score 7):

I agree. A lot of times, voting on Meta is about opinion, even in [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions, which can lead to warnings about question bans.

Since Meta SE (as of the split) is really is about opinion, we don't want to block people from asking questions if they are legitimate requests and follow the guidelines, even if not well received.

Take for instance my show vote buttons question. At the time (I don't now), I thought it was a good idea to show the vote buttons on these posts. It wasn't well received, and got downvoted a few times. Same thing with the home page question. Now I have a warning on questions that I might get question banned.

It doesn't seem like it'd be that much work to ban the occasional troll/flamer/whatever. They'd most likely troll the main site, not the Meta.

Answer (score 6):

I'm giving my small contribute on Stack Overflow from some years and I really love this community. I come on meta for the first time to complain about some behavior in which I saw some contradiction. I just wanted to express my point of view.

I did a big effort to detail my opinion very deeply, referencing also books of eminent psychologist, because my opinion were against the tide. *Dale Carnegie said that to increase your popularity, increase your influence, your prestige*, to achieve all this objective he explains that:

> **Fundamental Techniques in Handling People**
> *Don't criticize*, condemn, or *complain*.

So it's really easily to get downvoted when you try to go against the tide, unless you are a great communicator. And I'm not.

In meta people use to downvote to express disagreement. So a lot of disagreement, which can easily be achieved expressing unpopular ideas, will lead to a ban. This makes also hard not only to express opinions, but also to put the light on issues in meta.

For sure I could express better. I got upset when I started to see very hurried downvotes. But what happened is that I got largely downvoted and I was banned.

I've documented all the happening in a chat: https://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/693

In that chat I've tried to document the contradiction I see in some of our guidelines and the issues that are the logical consequence of these.

Meta SE is doing a great work. I hope I will be able to contribute to this community.