# account banned on Meta.SO. the automatic banning logic should be changed

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, meta, post-ban, ban

I get

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

on [my main account](https://stackexchange.com/users/45260/albert?tab=accounts) on Meta.SO. As you can see, I am an active Stackexchange user, mostly on SO. I always try to contribute to the value of all Stackexchange sites.

Of course I have read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) about the automatic ban system.

Improving my bad-voted questions on Meta.SO would not really help because downvotes were not because of the quality of the questions but because people were often/mostly disagreeing with my suggestion.

I understand that this is automatic and my ban cannot be undone by request. So I want to request that the logic behind the autoban on Meta.SO to be changed because downvotes mostly never mean that the question is bad.

Comment: The banning was already adapted recently for Meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197335/161198

Comment: Have you considered working your way out of the question ban by giving helpful answers?

Comment: *"because downvotes mostly never mean that the question is bad"* ... well, no. They often do mean exactly that.

Comment: What would you say downvotes mean then?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Whatever the person who cast them wants them to mean.  There is no single short answer beyond that.  Sometimes it's because a question is gibberish, sometimes it's because it's not constructive/hostile/annoying, sometimes it's because it makes a proposal that others disagree with, sometimes the author didn't do their research, sometimes the reader just misunderstood it, sometimes the reader is just mad and wants to downvote to vent, etc.  That list isn't anywhere near comprehensive.

Comment: Many of the problems with many of your questions have nothing to do with people disagreeing with you.  For example, you have a whole bunch of duplicate questions because you didn't do your research before asking commonly asked questions.  You also didn't phrase many of your questions constructively.  You began actively antagonizing the meta community.  When you poke the lion you can't expect it to retract it's claws before patting you on the back.

Comment: Using a feature-request tag will get downvotes when users feel the feature lacks proper requirements or vetting. Moreover, bypassing convention to use a secondary account to post yet another feature-request seems like gaming the system. Instead of thinking of what can personally help you, perhaps you should consider what will help the community. Vetted feature-requests, as in topics which have already had a series of discussion questions, tend to be received with more support.

Comment: @Servy: I realize there are many different reasons why a question can get downvoted. I was merely alluding to the fact that a downvote usually means there is something wrong with the question, and thus in the general sense is bad. ("Question" being the general act of posing a question, not just the actual question itself)

Comment: Also, it looks like you were just on the edge of the ban on Meta. Your main account is no longer banned after a couple of upvotes on your older questions.

Comment: @Bart: Have you looked at my question? Seriously, I don't know how to improve them. I really think all downvotes are only because of disagreement. Otherwise I don't see how my questions are bad. Or even if they are because they lacked background at the time of asking, how I should change that now. Please give me an example what I can add/improve on a question, I really don't know.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at your question. And I have linked to a recent adjustment to the banning to inform you about those changes. If you can't improve your questions, contribute in other ways still possible. And if what Brad says is correct, you should  no longer be banned any way.

Answer (score 15):

Of your [14 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146916/albert?tab=questions) - 6 are heavily down-voted, even by MSO standards.

In addition you've only provided [3 answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146916/albert?tab=answers).

While the automatic question ban allows for more down-voted posts than on the main site - after all MSO is supposed to be the place for discussion - there are limits. Clearly your ideas aren't finding favour with the rest of the community.

The question blocks are there to protect the site against low quality submissions and are only turned on where there is a demonstrable problem. Unfortunately MSO is one of those sites.

**Don't** delete your down-voted questions, see if you can improve any of them.

**Do** provide good answers, this will help (but I don't know the details of the algorithm so I can't say how many answers you'll need to provide or what score they'll have to get).

**Don't** continue to use this account. All that will happen is that it will get merged into your main account and you'll be in an even bigger hole.

Comment: This question is actually proposing that the q-ban algorithm be changed; it's not asking how to get unbanned once banned.  He's saying he shouldn't *have* to do these things.

Comment: @Servy - However, I'm saying that having 6 out of 14 questions down-voted and some of them quite heavily is bad even by MSO standards.

Comment: I agree.  But the OP doesn't.  This question is a proposal to say that, based on what he's done, he shouldn't be banned, and that the algorithm should be changed to *make it* so that he's not banned.  Your answer doesn't explain why that shouldn't happen, and why the q-ban algorithm shouldn't be changed, if that is your position.

Comment: I really don't see how I can improve on the questions. What questions are there where down-votes were because of the low-quality of the question and not because of disagreement? I would really like to get some help there or some suggestions because I really don't know and I feel kind of desperate and like people really wanting my suggestions be away from MSO. (Despite, for all my suggestions so far, I still think that they would improve the overall quality of SE, in the long term.) On this site, where downvotes are generally associated with disagreement, how does the auto-q-ban makes sense?

Comment: I am "in danger of being blocked" from questions on meta.  But looking at my history, it really seems that most of the downvotes are because someone interpreted the question as criticism.