# Disallow closing of questions with a certain number of question / answer upvotes

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

With reference to this currently open question
[Why C++11 compiler support still requires a flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373626/why-c11-compiler-support-still-requires-a-flag#comment30418408_20373626)

At the time of writing, it has 3 close votes yet has 7 question upvotes and the single answerer (11 upvotes) will have been awarded the enlightened badge (silver).

Therefore in the opinion of many (i) the question adds value and (ii) the answer adds value.

As a staring point for discussion, I suggest that 5 net question upvotes (and perhaps 5 answer net upvotes) should be enough to keep a question permanently open. Let's haggle over the numbers though. Thoughts?

Comment: Closed != Deleted. Having a closed question hanging around isn't that bad it just means new answers won't be accepted.

Comment: In Math SE  close=deleted (after a few days).

Why is is that I cannot delete my own question which has once upvoted answer but other users can delete a highly upvoted question (14 upvotes) with highly upvoted answer (26 upvotes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would have allowed questions about t-shirts and cartoons to remain open forever, despite the fact that they were off-topic.  We already have reopen votes to counter close votes.  Upvotes don't serve the same purpose, and often a good answer to a *borderline* question will already sway people to leave a question open.  The decision to open or close should be separate from, not based on, quantity of votes or answers.

Comment: You'd hope that t-shirts and cartoons would not have attained 5 question upvotes let alone an answer with 10 upvotes. Bots could spot collusion. But a good point about reopening though.

Comment: @Bathsheba Questions about cartoons and t-shirts got hundreds of upvotes, answers, and answers with hundreds of upvotes.

Comment: And, I hope, many folk still suffering the dreaded question ban (that I think I must be rapidly heading towards on meta ;-) )

Comment: @Bathsheba: No one will get question-banned for questions that get hundreds of upvotes.

Comment: @Wooble: I think I'm yet to attract a single upvote on meta ;-(

Comment: You've had 4, but I was talking about the people who posted questions about t-shirts.

Comment: @Bathsheba I haven't seen a Meta post about a Meta question ban recently, so my assumption is that they are fairly rare. Also - [Get rid of the question ban on Meta; suspend actively harmful users manually](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197335/161198) and [How do I participate in Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188)

Comment: And since fairly recently even more rare @Dukeling. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197335/161198