# Off-Topic Improvements could keep the conversation alive

Tags: feature-request, migration, off-topic

I find the off-topic experience on StackExchange sites to be very frustrating.
I usually arrive from a search engine and find the exact question I want to see an answer for is marked Off-Topic with the suggestion to ask again on a different site.

As a frequenter of various sites, especially StackOverflow, I can understand that it's important to keep questions on topic; However, as a viewer, this means I've arrived at a dead-end. To use a StackOverflow example, it feels very similar to finding an @Deprecated on a library method that appears to do exactly what I want with no explanation and no suggestion of alternatives.

**My first thought:** If a question is closed as Off-Topic AFTER there are up-voted answers, is it valid to kill the conversation?  People have indicated that they are getting value from the question / answers.

**My second thought:** Shouldn't steps be taken to prevent search engine traffic from being directed at an Off-Topic question?

Comment: Consider that once a search engine index a question (before it became off-topic), there is no telling how long it will stay indexed. Additionally, questions can get re-opened. It isn't like that's is always the end-state of a question.

Comment: @Oded That said, an off topic question is *much* harder to fix than, say, an unclear question.  If the whole thing is just radically off topic the only way to make it on topic is to completely change the entirety of the question, at least in most cases.

Comment: Closely related: [Disallow closing of questions with a certain number of question answer upvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209883)

Comment: Many of the off-topic questions I'm frustrated by are closed due to opinion vs fact aspect, not classically off-topic like asking what car to buy on a programming site. This is a tough line to draw in many cases because there are many different ways to achieve the same or similar results and opinion drives which way individuals prefer. I did not realize at 3k rep you can vote to reopen. I'll use that privilege if/when I get there

Answer (score -11):

My thoughts on how to improve the Off-Topic experience.  Maybe others have even better suggestions?

- No longer allow questions to be Closed Off-Topic

  - If they can be migrated to another StackExchange site, great, allow that migration to occur. Visitors arriving from a search engine should either be automatically redirected or one click away from the desired conversation's new home. (Very similar to existing duplicate functionality)
  - Another alternative would be to just let the question be down-voted or tagged Off-Topic without stopping the conversation. I don't see a lot of activity on questions with negative ratings. That's letting the community indicate that a Question is not providing value and letting it die of natural causes instead of murdering it.
- If the question isn't relevant to any other StackExchange sites, then they could be moved to a specific Off-Topic site. I don't have any evidence or strong feeling that an Off-Topic site would have value on it's own, but at least it would prevent a small percentage of reader from making subjective judgements to kill conversations that other users are getting value from.
- If a "Closed Off-Topic" state must still exist, that means that the community has deemed this page to be one that should be hidden (or preserved only as an example of what not to do).  If that is the case, then use Robots.txt to tell search engines to stop indexing that page and sending interested readers to dead conversations.

Comment: The sites are about questions and answers. Not conversations. Never that.

Comment: If we do let conversations continue, what's the impetus to ever ask on a different site where the post is on-topic?

Comment: SE has an excellent place for conversations - chat.

Comment: This is minor note regarding your last point: technically, a `robots.txt` file asks a search engine not to *crawl* (download and read) a page. It does not prevent a search engine from *indexing* a page.

Comment: You seem to be forgetting that these are not social networking sites. If the question is off-topic, it's irrelevant that some people find the information useful; it's **off-topic**, and doesn't belong on the site. There's no exception to that for questions some people find helpful to them, and there should not be one. The "off-topic site" that the question should be moved to is any one of the other non [se] sites that allow discussions and conversations or don't have any quality standards.

Comment: I completely disagree that questions and answers are not conversations. StackExchange harnesses collective human intelligence to help answer things that an individual can't. Simple questions may have one answer, but the most useful have many valid and invalid answers. Voting and commenting also provides value. By the time activity slows down, tens of people have contributed to the conversation. By the responses, I don't think the community is likely to see it my way. My opinion isn't going to change either, so I'll let it go. Closed questions are still a problem, but hey no site is perfect

Comment: @murgatroid99 that's a good point that a search engine may not remove the page from an existing index due to a later robots.txt change. I'd bet Google would, but I could be wrong

Comment: @KenWhite allowing linking a closed question to conversations on non-StackExchange sites sounds like a great idea. Not quite as good as an migration, but it would give someone sent by a search engine to a closed question the ability to link others to where they eventually found an answer or information that worked for them

Comment: @StanKurdziel: You can link any [se] post (closed or otherwise) anywhere off-site you want now. That has nothing to do with what I said. Off-topic questions should be closed as quickly as possible, because they're noise and clutter that interfere with on-topic questions receiving help. There should **not** be an official "off-topic" location anywhere within [se]. Off topic questions have the entire remainder of the internet to be asked; they don't belong here. There are a myriad of other locations where they can be posted.

Comment: I came across another example today of why **the current "Closed Off-Topic" behavior is SO BAD for the Stack Exchange community**: Googled: "os x 7zip", and 3rd hit is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9038982/431296 It's closed as Off-Topic. Fine - no arguments from me. It should be on a different stack exchange site, NOT stack overflow. But the page is now DEAD. The user on this page has no alternative but to return to google. That's a BAD, **LOW-QUALITY** result. It would be MUCH MUCH better if admins moved the question to the appropriate site instead of killing a highly ranked page

Comment: Number one hit for Google:"homebrew vs": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374366/what-is-the-difference-usage-of-homebrew-macports-or-other-package-installation actually has a comment linking to a better answer on the appropriate site: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32724/what-are-pros-and-cons-for-macports-fink-and-homebrew But since it isn't an actual "move", the google user needs to ignore the answers on the closed question and find and follow the link in comment to get the real answers. StackExchange could provide a much better experience with very little effort.