# Database questions - Make sqlfiddle/create/insert statements compulsory for most cases?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I see several SQL questions that don't have any or insufficient SQL code to create the sample tables and sample data. Example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788333/how-to-write-a-sql-window-function-to-find-event-by-date-of-another-event

Lack of sample code is acceptable in some cases. But it should not be allowed in cases where the problem is small - eg. small number of columns, tables and rows. No sample code can be allowed when the problem is trivial - eg. how do I select current date ? `SELECT GETDATE()`.

I feel that we should have code for sample tables because it -

1. Helps people to verify answers
2. Helps others to learn easily.

Can the mods put such questions on hold until the sample data is not created? I can't think of a feature for this right away. Perhaps you can suggest one ?

Sometimes I just create the sample code myself only so that I can solve an interesting problem. But, this distracts from the purpose of this website.

Comment: Such question could be closed with off-topic: lack enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Anyone mind telling me why the negative votes ?

Comment: @rene - can you please tell me how I can make this question better ? Thanks.

Comment: downvotes on meta sometimes mean disagreement, I guess the *compulsory* is the trigger

Comment: @rene - well, then that makes it mysterious. I am left wondering if its the quality of the question or just disagreement. I hope these downvotes will not affect my access to meta or any other SO for that matter.

Comment: @Borat You might be interested in reading [this question and its answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually).

Comment: Moderators already have plenty of work to do so adding to their workload is never a good idea when it is something that can easily be handled by normal users with a flag or close vote depending on the privileges that they have already earned on the site.

Comment: Why just database questions? There are plenty of question on other topics that lack sufficient code to diagnose, so they can all be closed, database included, for that reason.

Comment: @rene: I would be cautious about using that close reason unless there really isn't enough information to answer the question.  SQL questions don't necessarily require SQL code in the question to make it an answerable question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can the mods put such questions on hold until the sample data is not created ?

Well, if the question requires it and is unclear without it, a passing moderator could do that. But it's not necessarily a task for a moderator. The community should really pick that up. They all have the means to do so in various ways, and there's no reason to defer it to a mod.

And I don't really see a need for anything beyond that. If the question does not meet the criteria of a good, clear, answerable and on-topic question, then vote to close if you can. Or flag appropriately if you can't. That should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose what you want to do. If you don't want to answer such questions, don't answer them. If you think they deserve a downvote as per the text in the downvote hover, downvote them. If you think that they are inevitably 'unclear what you are asking', vote to close them. Then you find out of the crowd agrees.

We don't have 'mods' here in the sense you mean. The diamonds are not supposed to intervene in questions of question quality.