# Correct behavior when a question in Meta is mostly downvoted

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I just posted a question in Meta, and it is getting some upvotes, and many dowonvotes (4 vs 9 as of writing).

Since it is a feature-request, if the up and down votes are more or less the same, I understand that is good to keep the question even with a negative balance, since it could change. But, if a question is mostly downvoted for a time long enough, what is the best that should be done? Does it make sense to have a request that is clearly refused, or is it better to delete it to keep the site clean as we can?

Comment: No need to delete it.

Downvotes are not bad on Meta. It just means your idea was not well received. If anyone else in the future want to suggest the same then the community does not need to express their opinion again. 

Just refer to the duplicate.

Comment: @juergend good point that one of the future reference. Actually i wasent concerned about my reputation, but about having "garbage" in the site. But from that point of view, even a downvoted question is useful. Thanks!

Comment: Consider this: those downvotes come from people who saw the question on the front page and disagreed. A week from now, the only votes you'll get are people who seek out your post for wanting the same thing. And they are more likely to upvote. In time, it may very well balance out.

Comment: @mhlester thats another really good point

Comment: I'm... still waiting for one of mine to net zero rep though. May take a while ;)

Comment: @mhlester, me too. Can you give a help? `;)`

Comment: @JMCF, that's the catch 22. If you promote it, then people who see your post won't necessarily agree, and you're likely to get more downvotes again. It's only through organic patience that there is any hope for agreement to find you.

Comment: @mhlester, while I am aware of that catch in questions (I no longer link an unpopular question of mine!), I doubt anyone would check my profile looking for a question I asked to up-vote just to give me a down-vote. Though I haven't associated this behaviour with Catch-22, that's interesting.

Answer (score 18):

Keeping these questions around shows the community reaction to them at the time they were brought up.

They are important documentation and help frame a conversation, in particular for those who, in the future, are interested in bringing up the same or a similar suggestions. It can certainly help such people to at least formulate **new** ideas and reasoning.

For the long term life of the site, these are important.

As someone who asked such questions too, I understand where you are coming from - but due to the nature of meta voting, ban thresholds have been made to be much more difficult to reach. And in regards to reputation - since the ratio for 0 rep is 2uv/5dv, these tend to not matter much if you have any good questions already.

Comment: great explanation! I have been around SO for a while, but im absolutely new as an active user in meta. All this is really useful. Thanks Oded!

Comment: @Carlos - do note, that MSO is different to other meta sites - it holds its own reputation (and doesn't get it from its "parent" site). Though that is going to change soon.

Comment: a useful reference for _ban thresholds_ is [this answer in 'Get rid of the question ban on Meta; suspend actively harmful users manually'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197335/165773)