# Why do I get a question block warning?

Tags: support, meta, post-ban

I wanted to report a bug in the Android app here on MSE (as suggested by the help text) and got a warning "some of your questions have not been well received..."

As I only have asked two questions yet (both positive score) I wonder why.

Comment: For which site?

Comment: @servy here, I edited my question.

Comment: Anything to do with both of your questions being closed as duplicates, I wonder? Since flags and close votes are involved in that process, I bet that's the thing...

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions?  And as mentioned, having two closed questions is of course going to count against you.

Comment: Related?: [Get rid of the question ban on Meta; suspend actively harmful users manually](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179093/163250).

Comment: @servy not to my knowledge, no. In regard to two duplicates https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans states "one or two...  will not be a problem...", the same page mentions "heavily downvoted".

Comment: @guntbert And you're not question banned, you're just warned for moving in that direction.

Comment: @servy ack, but I can't know how close to a ban I am (and I definitely don't want to find out :-))

Comment: Yes it's because of the questions being closed as Oded (Stack Exchange developer) confirmed in chat, but he also reassured me that the warning appears long before the actual ban here on MSE. So no worry, you're still OK.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ...and now the OP has one more question closed as a duplicate, guaranteeing further warnings.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier well, this **is** a dupe. I believe he's still far above the pit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, I don't object to the closure. Just thinking of the irony of the situation: user is shown a warning (meant to help him avoid the ban), asks why it's shown and gets one step closer to the ban. Paved with good intentions all around, as usual.  Maybe the warning should begin with the First Rule of Ban Warnings...

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. when you say it like that... but this is how things work, for good and sometimes for bad. :)