# User consent is required before closing the question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, vote-to-close

I came across an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576571/assign-variable-in-if-condition-statement-good-practice-or-not) and tried to answer the question, but unfortunately, it was closed, so that I couldn't answer it.

It isn't easy to decide whether the question should be closed or not, so it should not be closed arbitrarily.

So what criteria should be used to judge?

I suggest that the **condition**<sup>{vote, bookmarking, ...}</sup> be taken into account as well.

Usually, the issue is bookmarked because they want to review it and because they want to be notified if the issue is updated.

If the issue is closed, these people can only review the issue, and no new updates will be possible in the future.

If a problem is really not suitable to appear in StackOverflow, I believe that few people are willing to bookmark or vote up this question.

So my suggestion is, is it possible to let these closed questions have the opportunity to restart it? (For example, it automatically opens when the `condition` is qualified.)

If the condition `continues` to update, it should be voted again when granted after cast a certain number of votes.

Comment: I don't see how bookmarks are a good indication for the quality of a question... Different people can bookmark questions for many different reasons. And if anything, if those people that bookmarked the question care about it and think it should not be closed, they can vote to reopen it... The more bookmarks - the more chances to reopen (according to your logic)

Comment: I don't get this at all. Why would bookmarks make a question on topic? If I ask about pizza on quantum computing, that is clearly off topic and that doesn't change even if I can get a million people to bookmark it, the question is still not about quantum computing. Essensially, you want to make topicallity a popularity contest and we might as well give up on SE at that point and just use Quora or something.

Comment: What if we don't look at the bookmarks and only look at the user's votes for the question?

Comment: That is just the same thing. Sites have topics so people can find help on that topic, if votes were how we mesured topics on any site, 90% of stuff on here would be cat pictures and memes with spelling mistakes in them.

Comment: The question you linked already has eleven answers, including an accepted one scored at +139. Topicality aside, are you *absolutely sure* that question needs another answer?

Comment: Accepted answers are great, but there may not be only one answer in a post that is helpful to the user. For example, the last new [reply was May 3, 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55970614/9935654), and someone still voted for it.

Comment: @F1Krazy I would like to add a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) with ``&&`` to make a judgment in if.
In addition, such a variable is not a const, and the value can be obtained outside the function and can be modified.
Also, if you use such a method, there is no way to apply it in the methods in the class. (should declare first)

Comment: Why is there such a high level of negative voting? For me, I would not easily vote against a post unless it was really wrong. My question is also just to suggest an idea, but now the problem is like suggesting an idea, and then people disagree and beat you up. I can accept the voice of opposition, but I feel awful about being beaten up.

Comment: Voting works a little bit differently on Meta. Here, it can be used to mean simply "I disagree with the idea you're suggesting". Unfortunately, this can lead to a feeling of being unfairly dogpiled, but rest assured that the downvotes are nothing personal, are not aimed as you as a person, and will not be held against you.

Comment: A closed question can easily be reopened.  All that has to happen is the author edit their question.

Comment: @F1Krazy thank you for clearing up my confusion. I'm much better. Although I didn't participate in the Olympics, maybe I'll break the Stackoverflow record for most negative votes...

Comment: Nah, you've got a *long* way to go to break that particular record. I think the most-downvoted post went down to something like -1200.

Comment: "I can accept the voice of opposition, but I feel awful about being beaten up." - So your happy provided we agree with you? How are you being beaten up by anyone here?  You shouldn't take downvotes personally.  **We simply don't like the proposed suggestion.**  Have tried my suggestion about editing the question, improving it and resolving any issues with the question, in order to get it reopened?

Comment: *…and will not be held against you* @F1Krazy My understanding was unlike the per site metas, it is possible to get question banned here. Which would mean this question’s score is going to be held against them in that regard.

Comment: Assuming this is still true: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually

Comment: @Carson "*I would like to add a destructuring assignment with && to make a judgment in if*" in what way would that answer the question which states asks "is it a good idea"? You'd be offering a different way to do the thing, not whether the thing is good or not. So, it's a *good thing*, that the question was closed. Your answer wouldn't have answered it.

Comment: Hi @BSMP, Thank you for your comment. I actually don't consider negative scores as honorable. On the contrary, I think it's rather shameful.
I honestly considered deleting the question, but I've already accepted the best answer... Anyway, I've re-edited the question, and hopefully, it will be the end of it.

Comment: Hi @VLAZ, you're right. If we're talking about whether my answer actually fits the question or not, it doesn't really fit that well. I actually browsed the article by searching in "javascript if and assign the value" to see if there was anything like the walrus operator (which is a keyword I came up with later), which means I didn't write that to answer the original author but to write to someone who came to this article for some reason like me. I understand that the community norm is to create a new article to answer your questions.

Comment: I can tolerate the answerer to extend some new issue from the question, as long as they do not go too far off-topic. Of course, this is only my personal view, perhaps I am a bit selfish, but after this discussion, I will not attend to restart the closed question. Everything will be natural when the original question to close people is not arbitrarily closed. This may also be the reason why I do not have 3000 points yet. I hope to have a better concept of making the right contribution to the community after I reach 3000 points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Usually, the issue is bookmarked because they want to review it and because they want to be notified if the issue is updated.

In that case, don't bookmark, but use the [follow feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/369802).

> If the issue is closed, these people can only review the issue, and no new updates will be possible in the future.

This isn't true: Closed questions can still be edited. Closed questions [*should* be edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions), if they can be salvaged.

> So my suggestion is, is it possible to let these closed questions have the opportunity to restart it? (For example, automatically open when bookmarks reached a count of the number.)

See the help center link in the previous sentence: Questions can be reopened. It doesn't happen based on bookmarks or follows though, it happens based on reopen votes, which are [a privilege you will earn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

This is good: Reopening should be a process kept separate from following and being notified of updates. People can follow the closed question and get notified of any updates that may make the post eligible for reopening, without having to worry that their following of the question will reopen it.

> Or is it possible for the people who marked the bookmarks to vote on whether to close the issue before closing?

Once you earn the privilege to vote to close, you can also vote against closing a question in the [close vote queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-close). Bookmarks or follows again should have nothing to do with that: The wish to remain updated about a question should be separate from voting for its suitability for a site.