# Does a change in reputation in meta cause a change in reputation in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

I am a Stack Overflow user.

I just wanted to know if any change in my reputation here will cause a change in my reputation in Stack Overflow?

Also, I just wanted to know since I am new to this site, is this site used to ask questions related to using Stackoverflow.com?

Comment: No, each StackOverflow and StackExchange site has reputation counters which work independently of eachother. This means that your reputation for each site will be an individual one.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: i have a score of 2 on my question (my first one, YAY!) but i did not get the Quorum badge in Stackoverflow...

Comment: @tenstar You have it now. Badges can take a little while to propagate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reputation here does not affect your reputation on Stack Overflow. You can earn some badges on Stack Overflow for posting on here.

The [Quroum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum) for one post with a score of 2 on Meta and the [Convention badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) for 10 posts with a score of 2 on Meta.

[Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/30/beta) badge for participation in Beta.

A badge of Stack Overflow for  [Precognition](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/892/precognitive) for following Area 51.

Comment: hang on , will find link to badges

Comment: exactly what i was going to ask...

Comment: Quorum and Convention

Comment: would u like me to post links??

Comment: yeah, sure. but just to warn all you answerers when i'm trying to accept, it comes that i can accept in 9 minutes. meanwhile i appreciated by up voting

Comment: One more doubt, which i couldn't find an answer for in this page: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation does my reputation change when someone plus votes on my comments, because my reputation seems to have increased by 3 and i see that i have 2 plus votes on my comment above. So does that mean i get 1.5 rep. per + vote on comments?

Comment: comments don't affect rep, they can be flagged of upvoted, upvoted comments can earn badges, I understand your concern about accepting an answer, but there is no rush

Comment: @tenstar: There is no reputation for comments. I think you got one up-vote and 1 downvote for the question (5-2 = 3)

Comment: i wonder from where did i get that +3 rep

Comment: aha.. why the downvote?? i missed my Quorum badge!! :)

Comment: ah yes it was 1 upvote and 1 downvote i just checked! @MidhunMP

Comment: @Yve what is beta?

Comment: @tenstar take a look at this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63401/what-is-private-beta-status and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152730/should-i-care-if-a-site-is-in-beta/152731#152731

Answer (score 3):

> ...change in my reputation here will cause a change in my reputation in stackoverflow?

No, you have independent reputation counters for Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow.

> ...is this site used to ask questions related to...

This site is a place to discuss Stack Overflow. If you feel that something isn't working as expected, or if you are confused about a particular element of the site, you can ask here.

From the [About](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) page:

> How do I use this site?
>
> - Ask questions about how the websites work.
> - Ask questions of the community.
> - Post bugs.
> - Suggest improvements.
> - Propose new features.

Comment: just to warn all you answerers when i'm trying to accept, it comes that i can accept in 9 minutes. meanwhile i appreciated by up voting

Comment: @tenstar No worries. Most of the people around here know about the limitations and time-restrictions. As long as you don't *"forget"* about it, everything's fine...

Answer (score 2):

> Does change in reputation in meta cause change in reputation in Stack Overflow?

No, both profiles are separated from each other and maintain differently.

However for other sites like programmers, superuser etc, they uses same profile for both main site as well as their respective meta site.

Comment: hey, thanks for ur answer! I upvoted!!

Answer (score 1):

I just reached 200 rep on S/O and when I hit that, all of my accounts (including META) had 100 rep added

Comment: Indeed, when you reach 200 on any one SE site, all of your other sites are given 100 rep for the association bonus (with the intent that anyone who's reasonably experienced on one site shouldn't have to deal with the 'new poster' restrictions of <100 rep).

Comment: That is the only exception to the rule posted above.